# Display check box as checked when false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, erb, formbuilder

The default functionality of the `check_box_tag` is to show it checked for `true` value hence the attribute "inactive" below would display as checked on `true`.

```
f.check_box :inactive
```

How can one have the opposite behaviour, i.e. show the checkbox checked when the value is `false` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f.check_box :inactive, checked: (!f.object.inactive)
```

Comment: Hi! Actually, it displays correctly (i.e. the opposite value), but it passes as well the opposite value on submission. I.e. it saves the opposite value automatically on each submission, even if the user hasn't touched the check box...

Comment: Do you know any way around this, so that a checked box is saving `false`?

Comment: Not out-of-the-box. It'll save it's checked value, like we're specifying it to. The best option is to show the box as checked when the value is true i.e. the default behavior. If you want to get your version to work i.e. ignore the value if the user hasn't changed it, you could add an HTML class to the checkbox and JavaScript to remove this class if a user changes the checkbox's value; then on the form's submission, you could find and ignore any checkboxes with this class before the form is submitted.